# duda en un if y simbolo !

Tags: php

tengo este if me lo explico un compañero pero no le entiendo bien

```
if (!($result = $db->sql_query($q)));
```

podrian explicarme como se lee y como actua?
 gracias

Comment: Lee el _!_ como _NO_, es decir, en tu mismo ejemplo: _si no $result = $db..._ por lo que es una forma de negar una condición para obtener lo que normalmente tendrias en la parte del _else_.

Comment: Puedes leerlo como te menciona track3r o como yo lo hago que leo Si (lo que está después de !) es falso entonces..

Comment: si es falso se  termina en; y si no es falso lo ejecuta?

Comment: A qué se deben los downvotes? Puede ser una pregunta básica, pero eso no amerita que se le vote negativamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` es llamado el opeardor de negacion. Este lo que hace es que niega la expresión booleana segun el resultado de la misma. Por ejemplo:

```
echo !true;
```

Notaras como imprime `false`, esto porque `false` es la negación de `true`.

En tu caso la funcion `$db->sql_query($q)` retorna un booleano. Ese resultado se guarda en `$result` por lo que `$result` ahora es de tipo `boolean`, si el resultado es `true`, este se niega a `false` por lo que el `if` no se cumple y se ignora su cuerpo, de lo contrario si retornase `false`, este se negaria y pasara a ser `true` por lo que si se ejecuta el cuerpo del `if`.

Este seria el codigo descompuesto para que se entienda mejor:

```
$result = $db->sql_query($q);
if (!$result)
{
 //...
}
```

El if solo se ejecutaria si $result fuera falso, ya que ! niega el valor `false` a `true`.

Comment: gracias ahora lo entiendo